# amchar 4 custom axes breaks shape

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

I need to customize the shape of the column break element on Amchart4.
Following the [Docs](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/#Breaks) there arent any mention abount how to change the shape.
By default is wave but i want to use some straight line with a custom element (es arrow up and down) on column.

Looking on [Master code](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/blob/master/src/.internal/charts/axes/AxisBreak.ts) i found a reference of an imported class

import { WavedLine } from "../../core/elements/WavedLine";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't replace axis break's `startLine`, `endLine`, and `fillShape` with something else. That would violate type restrictions that require those objects implementing `IWavedShape` interface.

That said, you can straighten the lines up by setting zero-height waves:

```
axisBreak.startLine.waveHeight = 0;
axisBreak.endLine.waveHeight = 0;
axisBreak.fillShape.waveHeight = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks!
is possible to get the offset position of the intersection between axis break and colum? (es: to add some html elment on it)

Comment: Nope, it's not possible. Sorry.